# iOS format specifies type int but the argument has type int *

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a method like this:

```
-(void)processSomeNumeber:(int *)number
{
    NSLog(@"show me the number %d", number);
}
```

But I'm getting this error:

> "format specifies type int but the argument has type int *"

Does anyone know why or how I can fix this?

Comment: change it to -(void)processSomeNumeber:(int)number

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use:

```
-(void)processSomeNumeber:(int )number
{
    NSLog(@"show me the number %d", number);   
}
```

Or

```
-(void)processSomeNumeber:(int *)number
{
    NSLog(@"show me the number %d", *number);   
}
```

Comment: Can someone elaborate on why this needs to be this way ?

Comment: @kursus: If you see the basics of C-pointers. Pointer variables(int *number) doesn't hold the value. It holds the address where the value is stored. To access the value either de-reference `*number` or don't use pointer at all.